# Excel - Way to check if number is within range in a single step?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bounds

In Excel, I am trying to check if a certain number is within a certain range *without* typing the number twice. Why? Because the number I am checking is part of a very large formula and I'm trying to avoid typing it twice. Helper cell could be used but I am trying to avoid, if possible.

Is there a way to effectively accomplish the formula shown below, except that without typing the `{very long expression}` twice?

```
= AND({very long expression}<{upper bound},{very long expression}>{lower bound})
```

**NOTE**

I am answering my own question here but I am wondering if anyone else has a better solution, or if there's just a built-in Excel function that already does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single condition to check if the absolute value of the very long expression offset by the average value of the upper and lower bounds is less than the upper bound offset by the average value of the upper and lower bounds.

Simple example below:

```
0 < x < 6

(average of 0 and 6 is 3, so subtract 3 from all expressions below)

-3 < x-3 < 3

abs(x-3) < 3
```

To incorporate this into an Excel formula, you can do this:

```
= ABS({long expression}-AVERAGE({upper},{lower}))<({upper}-AVERAGE({upper},{lower}))
```

The only repetition that occurs in this formula above is `AVERAGE({upper},{lower})`, but assuming the upper and lower bounds are either hardcoded or are single cell references, this formula will be shorter (and more efficient) than typing out the `{very long expression}` twice. And actually, if the upper and lower bounds are hardcoded, you could also just hardcode the average of them to make the formula even shorter.